# creating new elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was reading the basic documentation on using jquery at: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

In the section titled, "Creating New Elements", there is a second example which is as follows:

```
// Creating a new element with an attribute object
$( "<a/>", {
    html : "This is a <strong>new</strong> link",
    "class" : "new",
    href : "foo.html"
});
```

I do not understand this completely.

1. How is it that you are creating an element with invalid html as: the 'a' followed by the forward slash?
2. I have never seen an "html" attribute ever in my life.

Any explanations to this example would be helpful.

Comment: If it is the syntax that confuses you, the hash (i.e. what's inside {}) is being passed to a function, namely `$` and when it receives two such parameters it behaves in a given way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a/>` is merely a self-closing tag and it could just as easily be rewritten to be `$("<a></a>")` instead.

The value of the `html` property is what jQuery uses to ultimately set the inner HTML content.

Comment: So "<a />" is something parsed by jquery and automatically turned into "<a></a>"?

Comment: @robertrocha, no it's read on the DOM level and utilized by jQuery. It's a valid element, even without jQuery. [I swear](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/T5ryU/1/)

Answer (score 3):

`<a/>` indicates a tag with no content, otherwise known as a self-closing tag. Content is then added to it.

jQuery interprets attempting to set an `html` attribute as setting the link's content HTML.

That being said, the code is kinda butt-ugly. I would much prefer this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = "new";
a.href = "foo.html";
a.innerHTML = "This is a <strong>new</strong> link";
```

Or, for bonus points, remove that `innerHTML` line and replace it with:

```
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is a "));
a.appendChild(document.createElement('strong')).appendChild(document.createTextNode("new"));
a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" link"));
```

Comment: Why should one deny simplified jquery html operations, when jquery is present in the project?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link to the jquery documentation where it explains the "html" attribute in detail or on how to create elements with a better explanation and full explanation?

Comment: Ok the documentaion sovled it with this key phrase that made everything clear: "As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter"   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 0):

#### Self Closing `<a />`

Back when the 'new HTML' was being thought of (before HTML5), Web Developers decided that the next HTML should model after XML. So, XHTML was born. One of the markup conventions in XML is the self-closing tag, for tags that are just there to be there or only contain attributes. We still see this convention in modern HTML to this day. While some tags require an ending, like our `<a>` tag here, other don't like a `<br>` or an `<img>` tag, thus when XHTML became popular the new "cool" convention was to self-close and yell at people in forums who didn't do the same thing you were doing. That's all she wrote on that. Technically, it's the same as `<a></a>`.

#### HTML attribute

This isn't an attribute of the `<a>` element, but a property of the jQuery object that is created with `$('<a />')`. It's equivalent to the `html()` method of the jQuery library. It just assigns the `innerHTML` property of the element.

Comment: Appreciated. Do you have a link to the jquery documentation where it details it's html property not method?

Comment: I think this is better: "As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter" api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes